# Jura Ena 4 Troubleshooting

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a perplexing problem with my Jura Ena 4 (bought new in 2021).

For a little while now, it has been regularly (every 4-6 brews) performing the following behavior when brewing a coffee:

The machine will make the usual "I am about to brew a coffee"sounds but then suddenly, before the grinding process begins, will simply abort.

When I press the button to brew another coffee, steam comes out from the collection tray (probably evacuating the water in the pump?) and then it will start the brewing process again and always succeed.

This behavior tends to go away after a cleaning cycle, but always returns eventually.

Any ideas would be appreciated.